# Why does trySilentAuthentication not call finishedWithAuth:error:?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

I'm integrating Google Plus sign in with my iOS app. On the login screen when the Login with Google+ button has been tapped I call `authenticate`, the SDK opens the browser and after user consents they are taken back to my app and logged in, no problem about that. Then, on a subsequent app start, in my AppDelegate's `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method I'm calling `trySilentAuthentication` to see if the user has already been authenticated before. The documentation says that once `trySilentAuthentication` finishes, it should call `finishedWithAuth:error:` method from the delegate, but that never happens. Also, when I check `trySilentAuthentication`'s result, it returns `YES`, but nevertheless `GPPSignIn`'s `authentication` property is nil, which confuses me. Anyone can help?

Comment: This is hands down the most substandard SDK by a large corporation I have come across. Our solution involved setting a property in user defaults if the initial sign in works. Then after that we call authenticate normally since this doesn't show a web view. Have you found another solution since trySilentAuthentication literally only works if you have just signed in

Comment: @DanielGalasko This was a while ago, but rerunning the code now seems to affirm my old observations - that the `finishedWithAuth:error:` delegate method is getting called only if `trySilentAuthentication' finds an authenticated user. Otherwise, the delegate method is not called. And I also didn't find the return value of `trySilentAuthentication' of any use. So your solution seems alright. I did something similar, too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the delegate to GPPSignIn?
It should look something like this

```
[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;
```

where self is the same class that calls `trySilentAuthentication` and same class that has implementation of `finishedWithAuth:error:`

Comment: Yes, I've set the delegate prior to calling `trySilentAuthentication`. Ian Barber, a Google developer programs engineer, has a helpful blog post about "Common Issues With Google+ Sign-In On iOS". Inside it he writes: "(most of the time) calling trySilentAuthentication will fire the finishedWithAuth:error:". So I suppose I've stumbled across that rare case when it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this for some hours I realized that when       `trySilentauthentication` is called from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` it almost never calls `finishedWithAuth:error:` However if you call it in any other method than `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` it works. It also works if you call it in one of your View Controllers rather than the App Delegate.